# get index of item in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, template, cart-items

I want to change the templates `checkout/cart.phtml` and `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` respectively so that it shows the index of the item in the table (i.e. "Positions 1 through x").

I couldn't find a way to get the current index of the cart item in `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` though. Is there any way to do this? Other than with a `$GLOBALS` variable.

Comment: what is your magento version??

Comment: forgot to add the tag, I have edited the post accordingly